# Can we include a stylesheet link with an API as href attribute?

Tags: html, css

I would like to dynamically add an external CSS file. Until here, all is OK.
However, I would like to set as href attribute an url of an API that will generate and return the CSS file.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as the API serves a document whose MIME type is text/css it will work. The API needs to send a `Content-Type: text/css` response header along with the contents.